# Labels Not Appearing After Sequence of Layouts R

Tags: r, plot

I am running the following code:

```
par(bg="yellow", mar=c(2,2,2,2))
layout(matrix(c(rep(1,12),2:13),nrow=2,byrow=T),width=myWidth)
plot(days,sum_precip,type="l",xaxt="n",yaxt="n",ann=FALSE,
                      xlab="TEST",main="WEWQWE",ylab="dsads")
```

On the last statement, my plot fails to display any labels even after specifying this in arguments. Is it because my margins are too small?

I am trying to add a header for the x-axis for each of my graphs on the bottom row of the layout.

Example of Issue:

[image]

Note, I'm more curious about why this does not work. I know I can just specify an axis(..), but this is more out of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a solution using `mtext`. see ?mtext

> Text is written in one of the four margins of the current figure
>   region or one of the outer margins of the device region.

```
 par(bg="lightyellow", mar=c(2,2,2,2))
 layout(matrix(c(rep(1,12),2:13),nrow=2,byrow=T))

 replicate(13,
           {  plot(x=1:5,y=cumsum(1:5),type="l",xaxt="n",yaxt="n",ann=FALSE)
              mtext(text='TEST',side=1,line=1)
              mtext(text='dsads',side=2,line=1)

              })
```

[image]

**EDIT**

You can set the margin for every plot.

```
 par(bg="lightyellow", mar=c(2,2,2,0))
 layout(matrix(c(rep(1,12),2:13),nrow=2,byrow=T))
 for(i in 1:13){  
              if (i %in% 1:2){
                plot(x=1:5,y=cumsum(1:5),type="l",xaxt="n",yaxt="n",ann=FALSE)
                  mtext(text='TEST',side=1,line=1)
                  mtext(text='dsads',side=2,line=1)
              }else{
                par( mar=c(2,0,2,0))
                plot(x=1:5,y=cumsum(1:5),type="l",xaxt="n",yaxt="n",ann=FALSE)
              }
          }
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for however. Is there anyway to set the margins to c(2,0,2,0) and have only the first graph on the 2nd row have a y-axis ( so that the other 11 graphs share the same y-axis?) I've been having trouble specifying the margins for just 1 graph, it appears to be influencing all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah margins are too small.

Example:

```
par(mar=rep(4,4))
plot(1, 1, xaxt='n', xlab='x', yaxt='n', ylab='y')
```

[image: margins 4,4,4,4]

this shows the labels (sorry it's tiny).

However using `par(mar=rep(2,4))`:

[image: margins 2,2,2,2]

The labels are cut off.

You can use the `mgp` argument to modify the offset (in lines) of the axis text from the axis. In particular (`?par`), `mgp` is a vector of length 3 where `mgp[1]` is the lines between the plot and axis label, `mgp[2]` is for the axis line itself and `mpg[3]` is for the axis tick labels.

So:

```
par(mar=rep(2,4))
# mgp[2:3] irrelevant in this case as we have turned
# axis line/ticks off; doesn't matter what they are set to
plot(1, 1, xaxt='n', xlab='x', yaxt='n', ylab='y', mgp=c(1,0,0))
```

This will place the axis labels 1 line away from the axis (i.e. on the second line away) which just fits into our margin of 2,2,2,2.

[image: margins 2,2,2,2 with mgp]